# How can Unity be made more friendly to multiple monitors on a laptop?

Tags: 11.04, unity

When the laptop is connected to a new monitor while suspended (Which I do daily when I arrive home) and woken up, the unlock screen works fine, but Unity has several areas that are simply black. The mouse works in those areas, and Super-W shows windows in the black areas, but nothing in them is clickable. The black area includes approximately a 100-pixel bar at the top of the primary monitor (1600x900) and the entire secondary monitor (1280x1024).

Running "unity --replace" at the Alt-F2 prompt (which I can't see, but works) fixes it, but is there a way not to have to fix it each time?

Screenshot below:
[image: The Screenshot]
[image]
The black under the primary (left) monitor is normal - They're different heights.

/var/log/Xorg.0.log - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/603055/

lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0046] (rev 02)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: The files it looks like are needed are quite large - is there a way to upload them, or otherwise hide the text content from those who don't want to see it?

Comment: You can use pastebin.ubuntu.com.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've added /var/log/Xorg.0.log and lspca -nn | grep VGA. Is there anything else I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should probably be raised as a new Unity bug on Launchpad but a quick solution is to run that command when resuming using these forum [instructions](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1484156)